# Issue while run IONIC 2 app in android device

Tags: android, ionic2

I have added bellow line in my `config.xml` file.

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000"/>
```

When i run app in android device using `ionic run android -l -c` its displaying white screen for dome time after loading of splash screen. How can i resolve this?

here my `app.component.ts` file,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { AdMob, AdMobOptions, AdSize, AdExtras} from '@ionic-
native/admob';//import


import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { DetailsPage } from '../pages/details/details';
import { SettingModalPage } from '..Pages/setting-modal/setting-modal';


@Component({
templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
rootPage:any = HomePage;

constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, admob: AdMob) {
  platform.ready().then(() => {
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  statusBar.styleDefault();
  splashScreen.hide();

let options:AdMobOptions={
adId: 'ca-app-pub-5732334124058455/7973166445',
adSize: 'SMART_BANNER',
isTesting: false
 }

admob.createBanner(options).then(()=>{
   admob.showBanner(8)
 })

});
}
}
```

my `config.xml` file code,

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.nearbyapp493913" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>NearByApp</name>
  <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
  <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.103:8100"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.107:8100"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57"/>
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114"/>
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40"/>
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80"/>
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120"/>
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50"/>
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100"/>
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60"/>
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120"/>
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180"/>
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72"/>
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144"/>
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76"/>
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152"/>
    <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167"/>
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29"/>
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58"/>
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87"/>
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320"/>
  </platform>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300"/>
  <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
  </feature>
  <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="1.0.5"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.4"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="~2.0.2"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-admobpro" spec="~2.28.3"/>
  <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
</widget>
```

Comment: Does that happen only when you have added above line or?

Comment: yeah.. thats happen after added above line. Actuly I have added AdMob banner. but there some issue now generated. that is application error the connection to the server was unsuccessful i have tried to solved and i added <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000"/> in my config.xml file

Comment: have you any idea how can i solve this? @Sampath

Comment: Can't you test the app by reducing the `value="700000"` ?

Comment: One question.Now, don't you have any server errors after the above line?

Comment: No.. i don't have any server error after adding above line.. its just white screen display after loading of splash screen and before loading off application's home screen.

Comment: Can you show your `app.component.ts` file?

Comment: Ok.One last file :) `config.xml` ?

Comment: i have added `config.xml` file.

Comment: Hi, you find any solution? I am facing the same issue in ionic 3. I did't add addMob then else I am facing this. Can you please help me on this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

I think the only solution which you have is, remove the `AdMob` dependency from your `app.component.ts` file and implement that on the page component where you need to use it.And you have to set `LoadUrlTimeoutValue`as default like `<preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000"/>`.

**Old Answer**

Keep a backup of your `config.xml` file and do below changes and see that.

Remove below 2 lines in `config.xml` file.

```
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
```

Comment: I have applied this solution but  its still not working.

Comment: hmm.. did you reduce the `value="700000"` also?

Comment: i have reduce it and set value=`120000` but its still showing white screen. i have also tried to set `value=70000` then its showing `application error the connection to the server was unsuccessful`

Comment: Please see the **Update** on my post above.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `splashScreen.hide();` from top and add it to after `createBanner`, like this....

```
admob.createBanner(options).then(()=>{
   admob.showBanner(8)
})

splashScreen.hide();
```